# why some bash commands with pipe doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, pipe

I'm trying to implement my own shell, based on bash behavior, and i notice that there' some commands that doesn't work with pipes,
like if i have : `export AAA=test | cat`, for example this commands not going to add AAA to the environment variables, so it's like export didn't work,

but if i write : `export | cat`, it's going to print environment variable, so here, it's like export work,
the same with exit, unset ....
so can someone explain to me this behavior and how i can implement it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` in both cases executes in a *subshell*, whose environment is a copy of the parent shell's.

With `export | cat`, you cat the contents of the subshell's environment, which wasn't modified from the copy received from the parent, so you get output that matches what `export` alone would have output.

With `export AAA=test | cat`, you modify the environment of the subshell, not the calling shell. Further, `export` in this case doesn't write any output for `cat` to read. Once the pipe completes, the subshell is destroyed, and control reverts to the current shell, whose environment was not modified.

Comment: Minor nit: `export AAA=test | cat` does *not* actually modify the environment of the subshell.  *If* that subshell spawned another subshell, the environment of that subshell would have AAA in its environment, but the subshell running the `export` command does not have a modified environment.

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question, the problem here is in the case of pipe, export is not going to add anything to the environment variable of my shell, but in case without pipe it's going to work as expected, the same as exit,
if there's exit with pipe, the shell is no going to quit.

Comment: @REVERSI whether in the pipe or not, `export` does not modify the environment of the shell.  It only impacts the environment of subsequently executed commands.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think it depends on what you mean by "environment". `export AAA=test` certainly sets the value of a variable named `AAA` to `test` in the subshell. There's really no difference (AFAIK) between variables initialized from the parent's environment and variables set later. It is true that that exporting a name simply means marking it to use when constructing a child's environment, not shoving a variable into some separate namespace.

Comment: yeeh i know, it's not going to change the environment variables of the pparent shell (bash), but it's going to change the environment variable of my shell. but i just need to know why it add to the subshell environment varibale in case without pipe and if there's a pipe it's not going to add to the subshell environment variable

Comment: @chepner That's a valid point.  I think there is a *ton* of confusion over variables and environment variables though, and it's probably best to stick with a precise definition of "environment".

Comment: I guess there is a meaningful distinction on operating systems that limit the amount of memory available for the combined environment and arguments for a new command.

Comment: @REVERSI Most shells implement pipelines by forking a new processes for each command. Some shells (`bash` included, if the `lastpipe` option is set) will execute the *final* command in the current shell. I'm not aware of any shell that will execute any other command in the current shell, although I don't believe POSIX actually forbids it.

Comment: @chepner Thank you sooo much, that's what i was looking for